# Let $U\in V$ be a balanced set. Then $cl(U)$ is balenced and $int(U)$ is balenced provided that $0 \in int(U)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$cl(U)$ is the closure of $U$, $int(U)$ is the interior of $U$

> Claim: let $(V,T)$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $U \subset V$ be a balenced set. Then $cl(U)$ is balenced, and $int(U)$ is balenced provided that $0 \in int(U)$

For the closure is used that if $A \subset B$ then $cl (A) \subset cl (B)$

Thus since $\alpha U \subset U$ it follows that $cl(\alpha U) = \alpha cl(U) \subset cl(U)$.

Then similiar with the interior $int(\alpha U)  = \alpha int(U) \subset int (U)$.

Then I thought about this a Little while and some questions came to mind.

- Why do we need that $0 \in int(U)$
- How can I be certain that $cl(\alpha) = \alpha$, $int ( \alpha) = \alpha$? According to the solution to the problem I provided an correct solution, but I'm doubtful that I fully understood it.

Comment: You need to use the fact that $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is a homeomomorphism, unless $\alpha =0$, in which case you need $0\in U^o$ for the claim to be true.

Comment: I have been thinking about you comment and I dont see how it answers why $cl(\alpha) = \alpha$, $int(\alpha) = \alpha$?

Comment: what does $cl(\alpha)$ mean? $\alpha$ is an element of the scalar field. If you mean that $cl(\alpha A)=\alpha cl(A)$ and similarly for $int$, then these equalities hold because the map $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is a homoemorphism.

Comment: What exaclty in the homeomorphism says that, is it the continuity, bijectivety? Or those properties togethere. We have $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ and $A \in V$ so the map $\mathbb{F} \times V \to V$ gives that $cl( \{\alpha\} \times A ) = cl(\{\alpha\}) \times cl(A) \to cl(\alpha)cl(A)$. Now you say that since the map is a homeomorphism then we get $=\alpha cl(A)$. Can you explain the later part in more detail? @chilangoincomprendido